# Conversation conflicts in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft bot framework V4 nodejs sample 24 for a leave management bot. I have added this bot to ms teams. The problem I am facing is when multiple users are using the bot at once, the conversation data of others are being shown in the other user bot.

In the emulator, most of the time it works correctly but in teams it’s not working properly.

I have developed a chatbot for leave management. When a user types 'apply leave', it will begin an apply leave dialog where in waterfall step it will ask a couple of questions like leave type, start date, end date etc. This bot is sideloaded in teams (created using app studio manifest and pointed to a bot hosted on azure). In my organization everyone can use this bot to apply leave. Now suppose multiple people are trying to apply leave, then is some cases for some users, start date is already present which is actually given by someone else in their bot. Similarly, sometimes it shows other user provided leave type to someone else.

Comment: Looks like some race condition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: @Tony What are you on about?

Comment: @sandeep Do you mean that in a group conversation (multiple users in one convo, including the bot), everyone is seeing the conversation? Or do you mean a series of 1-on-1's where User A messages bot, then User B messages bot, User A gets the response that should have gone to user B?

Comment: @sandeep Please share a screenshot or a video recording to better understand the issue.

Comment: I have provided more information on it. please help me to solve this issue. do I need to store and compare any id's? if so how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing all the global variables and by storing all the values in the step context as an object.